# Can't boot after an upgrade to 16.04.1. Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!

Tags: boot, kernel, virtualbox

I had a 14.04 installation inside VirtualBox, and today I tried to update it to 16.04. It fails to boot after this. Selecting older kernel version from the boot menu and/or recovery mode doesn't help.
Any ideas?

[image: Boot dump]

Comment: @David Foerster, it's a different version.

Comment: @David Foerster, there is no answer there. And I didn't install other shell and didn't change anything in my system.